# How to generate different noise in LTspice from run to run

Tags: noise, simulation, ltspice, random

I'm trying to simulate noise in my circuit, and ideally want to get a histogram of a certain parameter affected by that noise over many runs. However, when I use the white() command in LTspice, or variations of rand(), I get the same result from run-to-run. Is there a way to randomize the seed so that I get different white noise every iteration?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very interesting question and providing a histogram makes it seem like you're trying to predict noise in a circuit. I believe you could be getting the same results is because the simulations likely assume that the circuit is always initially untouched and unadulterated. I don't think there are options to provide a "seed" for your noise analysis. There's a [similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305768/how-to-set-seed-in-ltspice-simulation) that's been asked here. Maybe that can help.

Comment: Use the rand() to vary the starting point of your .tran simulation.

Comment: LTspice can read an external WAV file, though writing your own controllable noise generator and putting it in via a file seems a very clunky way of going about it. Similarly, you could create an m-sequence in the simulation. Several instances of white() delayed by different amounts and added together might get you sufficiently different noise simulations.

Comment: Use the .STEP card and create a LIST of values that you add to white(). Then each run would start at a different place in the sequence. Log data and process. You could also use a PWL file with .TRAN if you wanted to do make changes every so often to the base seed you use in white(), which might allow a single run to start at different "places" so that an overall accumulation appears like what you want. Also see [this article](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-perform-transient-analysis-noise-simulation-LTspice/). If you write what you need, perhaps a better answer?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called a monte carlo simulation, LT Spice is limited here compared to comercial products as, as far as I know, only 3 parameters can be varied at the same run, but to me it always was sufficient.

just googled a tutorial: http://electronicsbeliever.com/monte-carlo-simulation-using-ltspice-step-by-step-tutorials/

but you will find many more...

Comment: The limit on the number of `.step`ped values is <strike>2</strike> 3 (you were right), but it can be circumvented to any numer by using `table()` (a bit cumbersome, but certainly not impossible). Also, for OP's case, you don't need to use more than one parameter: `white(x+time)` with `.param x=mc(a,b)` (`a` and `b` being some numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `.step` commands together with `WHITE` as shown below.

[image: LTSpice circuit]

In effect this starts the run from different points in time.  The output voltage in this example is as below.

[image: Output]

Thanks to Jonk for this answer in comments.  Added here in case linked page moves.